# How to password protect pages in WordPress

Tags: login, password, user-access

Every article and help document I find on this topic is focused on the WordPress built-in feature using the page->Visibility setting which is extremely limited and useless for true page protection.

I want staff to be registered with their own individual logins in Users which I have done using Profile Press and on login, I can redirect them to a specific page - easy.

The problem first came when people try to access a protected page directly so to resolve this:

1. I copied the `Page Template` and renamed it `Protected Page Template`
2. I added some code to `functions.php`:

`function check_is_logged_in( ) {
        global $post;
        if ( !is_user_logged_in () && get_page_template_slug($post->ID)=='page-protected.php' ) :
            wp_redirect( home_url().'/log-in/', 302 );
            exit;
        endif;
    }
    add_action( 'get_header', 'check_is_logged_in' );`

This partially resolved my issue so that if anyone tried to access the page directly, they were redirected and now, all I need to do is set the Page Template to `Protected Page Template` - Fixed.

But...

Now I have installed the PressApps Knowledge Base plugin and I want this to also be password protected BUT, get_page_template_slug() returns `empty` and is not included.

Is there another value I can use and test to identify the page template or page type?

Comment: FYI - KnowledgeBase has a "Template" selection - it currently uses page.php even though I have selected page-protected.php so this feature is broken, hence why I'm looking for an alternative

Answer (score 0):

The template name is stored in the postmeta table, you can identify the page template by different ways but i would do with like:

```
1. $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    echo "Template: " . $template;
2. echo basename( get_page_template() )
```